# Ionic grid not showing in a row

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to show my div in a row like 2x2 but its showing 3 in a row.

```
    <ion-grid no-padding class="member">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let f of fl" > <!-- JUST ADD A col-4 attribute -->
          <div class="mem-title">
            <div class="block_container6">
              <div class="bloc6">{{f.name}} </div>
              <div class="bloc61">{{f.age}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

.block_container6 > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}
.bloc6{
  font-size:10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF ;
}

.bloc61{
  font-size:10px;
  color: #FFFFFF ;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

[image]

as you can see in image i have 3 divs in a row i need to show 2.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ionic 4 you can do it like this bellow :

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size-lg="6" size-md="8" size-sm="12" size="12" *ngFor="let f of fl;">
      <ion-card>
        <div>NAME : {{f.name}} </div>
        <div>AGE  : {{f.age}} </div>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

you can change `size-lg`, `size-md` and `size-sm` as you want. and get this result ↓

[image]

or this result if you change `size-lg=4`, `size-md=6` and `size-lg=10`.

[image]